# Scanning barcodes using webcam in web applications using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate scanning barcode in web application.
Scenario is like 
1.Opening the web application
2. Open the webcam in web application 
3. Scan the barcode 
4. Display the results

Is it possible to do that?
If possible could someone please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

scanning barcode via webcam is not possible in automation. you can use any dump service to overcome this.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Whether we need developers help to achieve this?